# Delete text that is before a character

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to keep only the text after "Background", but I didn't have success trying to do it. For instance, I have a comment like this:

> 05/2022: AB: 6/20/22 - I'm learning how to use pandas library.
>
> Background: I'm trying to learn python.

How can I make all cells have only the background comment? It should look like this:

> Background: I'm trying to learn python.

Please see my code below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\R\Desktop\PythonLib\data\52022.xlsx")

comments = df["Comment"]

df['new_background'] = df["Comment"].str.split('Background:').str[0]

print(df["new_background"])
```

Comment: you can use `df["Comment"].removeprefix('Background:')`

Comment: `df['new_background'] = df["Comment"].str.extract(r'(Background:.*)')`?

Comment: df['new_background'] = df[df['Comment'].str.startswith('Background')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a sample of your data.

That said, you should probably do:

```
df['new_background'] = df["Comment"].str.replace(r'.*(?=Background:)',
                                                 '', regex=True)
```

Or, if you want NaN in case of missing background:

```
df['new_background'] = df["Comment"].str.extract(r'(Background:.*)')
```

Comment: hello, unfortunately I can't, but all the comments follow the same pattern, with a text and a new paragraph with the background.

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Comment: The second answer worked fine, thanks! 
So the ".*" entry keeps everything after the word?

Comment: Yes. The first option deletes what is before Background, the second one keeps Background and everything after.